# The JRE was not found in directory C:\Program Files\Java\JDK18~1.0_2 when starting weblogic server

Tags: command-prompt, soa, weblogic12c, java-home, oracle-soa

I have installed Oracle soa suite quickstart 12c (12.2.1.4.0) in windows 7. The java version i'm using is jdk1.8.0_241.

After creating a standalone domain, when i tried to start the weblogic server using startWeblogic.cmd I got the following error.

```
The JRE was not found in directory C:\Program Files\Java\JDK18~1.0_2 <JAVA_HOME>
Please edit your environment and set the JAVA_HOME variable to the root directory of your Java installation.
```

[Link to my cmd window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvSGe.png)

I have set the JAVA_HOME variable in my environment as follows

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241
```

Please suggest solutions to fix this issue.

Comment: Avoid using spaces in path when installing WebLogic or Fusion Middleware products. Try to use quotes when you set your JAVA_HOME.
set JAVA_HOME="C:\...."

Answer (score 6):

You should set JDK path in 'setDomainEnv.cmd' file.

1. Open 'setDomainEnv.cmd' file.

   ```
   (File path in my local PC is 'C:\oracle\mw\wls\dom_01\bin')
   ```
2. Update the 'BEA_JAVA_HOME' path to your JDK home path.

   (Ex: `set BEA_JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_171`)

NOTE: To find the directory short path in Windows, use `dir /x` in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by following below steps.

First ,this error is caused by space in java installation directory
(as in C:**Program Files**\Java\jdk1.8.0_241)

To overcome this you need to use quotes to set JAVA_HOME in some files in your Oracle home.

Few file where you need to check

```
oracle_home/middleware/oui/bin/launch.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/oui/bin/viewInventory.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/oui/bin/compareInventory.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/oui/bin/setProperty.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/oui/.globalEnv.properties
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/bin/setNMJavaHome.cmd
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/init-info/domain-info.xml
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/init-info/startscript.xml
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/init-info/tokenValue.properties
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/init-`info/nodemanager-properties.xml
oracle_home/middleware/user_projects/domains/wls_domain/nodemanager/nodemanager.properties
```

In the above files if you find any lines like

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241 

if NOT exist %JAVA_HOME%\lib

set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

set JAVA_HOME=%%~fsi
```

Modify them to below format with quotes and save them.

``````
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241" 

if NOT exist "%JAVA_HOME%\lib"

set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"

set "JAVA_HOME=%%~fsi"

`````

Now your system will recognize the java home without trouble
``````

Answer (score 0):

I was getting following error when i started my weblogic 12:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The JRE was not found in directory C:\PROGRA~1\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot. (JAVA_HOME)
Please edit your environment and set the JAVA_HOME
variable to point to the root directory of your Java installation.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

JDK I used was : **Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot**

Following below steps:

1. create a folder "**jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot**" in **C:** drive.
2. Copy the content of "**jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot**" folder from "**C:\PROGRA~1\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot**" to **C:\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot**.
3. Update **JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk8\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre** in **..\base_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd** file.
4. Start weblogic now.

Answer (score 0):

just in case this can still be usefull for anyone.
Just create an empty folder with exactly old jdk name and copy the content of thw new version inside this new folder.
Basically both folders will have the same new java files...